# How can I iterate over the characters in a string, and change them?

Tags: javascript

I want to take a string, and change each character. I.e. A becomes E or F becomes C.

what I have is this:

```
function convert(){
  var text=document.getElementById('textInp').value;
  alert(text);
  for()
}
```

I don't know what to do in the for loop

Comment: Strings are immutable in JS, so you can only create a new string. // How to get the character at a certain position is something you can research yourself. And then, in your loop you either append the original character or the replacement to your new string.

Answer (score 4):

You can iterate over each of the characters in the text like this

```
for (var x = 0; x < text.length; x++)
{
    var c = text.charAt(x);
    //Add code here to do the translation
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `text.charAt(x)` rater than `string.charAt(x)` ?

Comment: You are correct @IggyPass. I've updated the code. Good eye! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can split and join your String

```
function convert(){
   var text = document.getElementById('textInp').value;
   alert(text);
   text = text.split('A').join('E').split("F").join("C");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `string` length and iterate and replace whatever you want.

```
for(var i=0 ; i < yourstring.length ; i++){
    yourstring= yourstring.replace(yourstring[i],"yourvalue")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this `split("")` split the string with space .and match the letter then replace using map

```js
function convert(){
  var text=document.getElementById('textInp').value;
 console.log(text.split("").map(a=> a= a.toUpperCase() == 'A'? 'E':a.toUpperCase() == 'F'?'C':a ).join(""))
}
```

```html
<input id="textInp" value="AonFncdcd">
<button onclick="convert()">click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a **direct option** to iterate over a string directly: to use `for...of` or `for...in`:

```js
function convert(){
  let text = document.getElementById('textInp').value;
  for(let i in text) {
    // Do something
    console.info('i:', i, ' char: ', text[i])
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="textInp" value="Your input">
<button onclick="convert()">click</button>
```